# How does this recursive method for merging sorted Linked Lists work?

Tags: list, recursion, merge, sorting

Given this method:

```
mergeSorted(struct ListNode * a, struct ListNode * b) {

    struct ListNode * result = NULL;
    if (a == NULL) return b;
    if (b == NULL) return a;

    if (a->data <= b->data) {
        result = a;
        result->next = mergeSorted(a->next, b);
    }
    else {
        result = b;
        result->next = mergeSorted(a, b->next);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I understand how the list becomes sorted except for the first line where it sets the struct result to NULL. Each time the method is called recursively, how is the result list not set back to NULL? My first thought is that it is the pointer being set to NULL and not the actual contents of the list itself, but that still does not bring myself to a full understanding. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Because `result` is being assigned to later in the function.

Comment: This code appears to be correct and is very clever.  I'd recommend that you grab a pencil and paper and work through the algorithm for a pair of small sample sorted linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

'result' is defined within the function. It does not affect other iterations of this function which have 'result' within their own local scope.

Each time the function returns, it appends the local contents of 'result' onto the end of 'result' from the calling function.

```
result->next = mergeSorted(..);
```

This recursive return/append builds the entire sorted list and eventually returns in from where it was initially called.

Answer (score 0):

The NULL assignment is being given to a new struct listnode pointer which is there to return the result, not the incoming values, and the result pointer from the previous iteration of the function is not touched by this new pointer's creation and NULL assignment (this is a scope thing, the new pointer has the same name but is not the same pointer since it exists within an entirely new scope).

Whats happening is you are:

- Call this function and pass it one element from the struct for both a and b,
- Creat a new pointer to hold the return value and assigning that new pointer NULL value,
- Check if a or b is NULL, if either is NULL you return the other (though this might be a weakness in the function since if BOTH are NULL it will return a NULL, which may or may not be ok depending on whats happening outside the function)
- The function then compares the values of A and B current listnode, and takes the smaller of the two and adds it to the result struct.
- After this assignment the function increments the result struct to its next element and calls mergeSorted again with A and B (one of which will be incremented to next value depending on which one's value was pulled to fill the result struct)

At each level of recursion your result structs are only one value, until the recursion ends and starts to unravel, which results in each level of recursion reporting the its result to the previous iterations result struct until you reach the original call.

The only thing Im curious about is how this recursion actually ends, I don't see any reason this thing would stop going after each struct its dealing with has been consumed (unless setting struct result = struct a somehow consumes all the data in a and makes it NULL, Im not too familiar with C structs anymore).